# Oldest and earliest time in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I do have a table that has information about users and when they contacted us.
for example

```
ID | User | contct_time
1  | U1   | 2008-08-02 15:57:02+02
2  | U1   | 2008-08-02 15:57:02+02
3  | U1   | 2009-02-14 16:23:53+01
4  | U2   | 2009-02-15 16:01:08+01
5  | U2   | 2009-04-25 15:41:08+02
6  | U2   | 2009-07-19 14:34:49+02
7  | U2   | 2010-08-30 14:15:40+02
```

I want to find find the users whose the difference between first contact to the last one is less than a month.
SO i need to firs,
for each users get the earliest and latest time and differentiate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` on the user column to bucket the rows per group. Combine it with MIN / MAX moved to the HAVING clause so they are calculated after the grouping has been performed:

```
SELECT User FROM table 
GROUP BY User 
HAVING (MAX(contct_time) - MIN(contct_time)) <= INTERVAL '1 month'
```